# Bash: increase a version number in a Java properties file (Codename One version)

Tags: bash, codenameone

I have a Netbeans project (it's a Codename One project), that executes a `build.xml` ant build script. I modified that `build.xml` to execute an external bash script for some targets, for example:

```
<target name="build-for-ios-device" depends="clean,copy-ios-override,copy-libs,jar,clean-override">
        <exec executable="/home/francesco/Projects/SimpleFronted/increaseVersion.sh">
        </exec>
```

The purpose of that script is to update the property:

```
codename1.version=1.102
```

inside the properties file `codenameone_settings.properties`.
As you can guess, in this way I update the version number of the project automatically every time that I do a new build.

The problem is that my Bash script doesn't work correctly in all cases. For example, if the version number is between `1.000` and `1.099` it doesn't work, but if it is `1.100` it works.

I don't understand what it is wrong in my script. Can you please help me to fix it? Ideally it should work for every version number, from `0.001` to any greater version. I always want three digits after the point. Thank you.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Increase version..."
cd /home/francesco/Projects/SimpleFronted/

file="./codenameone_settings.properties"

if [ -f "$file" ]
then
  echo "$file found."

  while IFS='=' read -r key value
  do
    key=$(echo $key | tr '.' '_')
    eval ${key}=\${value}
  done < "$file"

  echo "OLD codename1.version="${codename1_version}
  codename1_version=$(echo "scale=3;(${codename1_version}*1000+1)/1000;" | bc | awk '{printf "%d.%03d", ($0 * 1000 / 1000), ($0 * 1000 % 1000)}')
  echo "NEW codename1.version="${codename1_version}
  sed -i "s/codename1.version=[^ ]*/codename1.version=$codename1_version/g" codenameone_settings.properties

else
  echo "$file not found."
fi
```

I'm using Bash `4.4.19(1)-release` on Linux Mint 19

Comment: Add file codenameone_settings.properties to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus I suppose that it's not relevant for the question, because it's a standard Java properties file and it contains sensitive data. You can create an empty file, add the only line that I reported `codename1.version=1.102` and name the file as `codenameone_settings.properties`: I've just tested that, in this case, the issue is the same as I described, if you run the Bash script multiple times.

Comment: IMHO, there's a lot of extra stuff in that script, it could all be done with one `awk` script. But to understand what is happening in your script, you're best to debug it yourself. Open up a 2nd terminal and copy/paste one line of code at a time (or block for the `while` loop). turning on `set -x` in the terminal will show you what values are being substituted for shell variables. You may need to add something like `echo "key=${key}XXX"` to understand it all. You especially need to deconstruct the monster line `codename1_version=$(echo "scale=3...` do that one step at a time. Good luck!

Comment: I"m busy today, but I bet if you put a bounty on this for an `awk` solution, you'll get some great stuff. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
codename1_version=$(echo "scale=3;(${codename1_version}*1000+1)/1000;" | bc | awk '{printf "%d.%03d", ($0 * 1000 / 1000), ($0 * 1000 % 1000)}')
```

fails for numbers from 1.001 to 1.099. The output of `bc` is correct, so it seems a problem of `awk`. I'm not sure if it's a problem of my code or a bug of `awk`, however a simple solution is to avoid `awk` at all, which purpose, in this case, is to add a leading zero for numbers less that 1. This can be done in a different easier way:

```
codename1_version=$(echo "scale=3; if(${codename1_version} < 0.999) print 0; (${codename1_version}*1000+1)/1000;" | bc)
```

Note that I wrote `${codename1_version} < 0.999)` instead of `${codename1_version} < 1)` because the version number is going to be increased.

However, thank you for the comments.

Comment: Generally version numbers are really hard on devices. E.g. in Android the actual version number is an integer so we multiply the decimal value by 100. On iOS 1.1 and 1.10 become the same number as they are both 1.1 in decimal.